# How can I get extended attribute "keywords" of a file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file

I'm trying to find a way to extract filesystem metadata for a file, like 'keywords','author' and other like in Widnows file properties window.

I've find out a lot of ways to get exif data, but not extended file attributes metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

1. Use a hacky existing solution that makes CLI calls to grab the information. [This package](https://github.com/Jack-Barry/get-file-properties#readme) goes this route, but it's a deprecated package for some reason. However, the source code gives you an idea of how to do that.
2. Use a package, or develop one yourself, that binds to the underlying Win32 API or the more modern [WinRT API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties?view=winrt-22621).
3. Perhaps use [edge-js](https://github.com/agracio/edge-js) to make .NET calls in the actual node process.

Note that doing this means this stuff will only work on Windows. As soon as you have native bindings, you are on your own to develop support for multiple platforms.

(2) or (3) Is preferable as opposed to having to fork CLI commands from your node app.

For (2) The [NodeRT](https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT) project is your best bet for doing it without writing the C code yourself. It is however a bit unmaintained, but it could be fine. You would want the [@nodert-win10-rs3/windows.storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nodert-win10-rs3/windows.storage) and [@nodert-win10-rs3/windows.storage.fileproperties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nodert-win10-rs3/windows.storage.fileproperties) package I believe.

That should allow you to effectively make calls to the underlying WinRT APIs.

This is pseudo-code, but it will be something like:

```
const path = require('path')
const StorageFile = require('@nodert-win10-rs3/windows.storage')

// WinRT needs you to import all the namespaces that might be used even if they are actually called by other namespaces indirectly.
const FileProperties = require('@nodert-win10-rs3/windows.storage.fileproperties')


async function getFileProperties(filePath) {
    try {
        const file = await StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync(filePath)
        const properties = file.properties
        return await properties.retrievePropertiesAsync(['System.Author', 'System.Keywords'])

    } catch (err) {
        // Handle error
    }
}

const contentProperties = await getFileProperties(path.resolve('./your-file.whatever'))


console.log(contentProperties['System.Author'], contentProperties['System.Keywords'])
```

For (3) it would just be a case of calling some small C# code with `edge-js` `edge.func()`. This actually might be the path of least resistance, as this seems more supported than NodeRT.

Comment: I've tried such methods, but it returns empty string. May be Win11 works some other way than OS's before. But in linux I've tried getfattr and others - and don't get any result...

Comment: Try the edge-js method -- number 3. Honestly that has the most promise.

Answer (score -1):

It was IPTC properties.
Found npm ExifReader that was able to read everything I need.